# How to best extract pattern from list/string type object in Python

Tags: python, regex, google-maps

I'm playing around with Google Maps Directions API. The API returns a lengthy list of length 1, see below. I'd like to extract travel duration from it, which appears after the string "duration_in_traffic" like this:

u'duration_in_traffic': {u'text': u'4 hours 3 mins', u'value': 14601}

Regular expressions doesn't seem to work here because the API returns a list of length 1 (several output parameters separated by commas but surrounded by nested brackets, making it impossible to output the "duration" line).

How do I either convert this list into a string so I can do regex, or better, split it into multiple lines so I can pick the duration line?

Here's the first chunk of the output of the directions API, in case it helps:

[{u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u'ounwFrkubM_Xp`@ka@i@igAwHsxAkN}P|A_aAoh@k~@{l@}hBqgAgiCk_BshB{uAe`B{q@*iAe*@qz@yh@ceAwq@sv@gaAoe@uf@ol@wA{OcQ|Fo`AmJmg@akAoVo_B_a@aOqQcRw_A~Ms`@|\q`Cp^qxBq@kVud@e]sg@iVko@cWi^}]mg@jBob@}`@aw@esBsFie@}RcWoRw_@{@qj@o`@gh@yJc_@ge@wg@q_Au}@gYaYet@kSet@_a@{Oet@hEya@e\\yvAiHgVw^qSakAuh@auAn^wh@c]mp@kD}z@m[m~@_sAgMc}Avk@gy@eNu{Aab@wcAgMu{AkEihB_u@{rB{t@sfDnMkgEek@iuBeq@gpAid@k}Am]eoBg`@{sA}wAa{CoKmaAzBcaBaq@k|DwQuaAm^_m@{}@amA{UqbAgYw}Ak`@q\\ak@em@_hAmy@mm@}_AcSwzAhAawAiXuwCqKg}CvCstB{PixCgd@yeC}ImlBmg@saAurA}jAydBk|AwgAct@alAsRm^_p@sk@wzCymCukDy}@yiAeLyx@ma@o~Aca@wvAcL_c@{l@}o@a\\qg@ug@y_BweAeiB}p@uq@yr@k[qtCar@wjAam@o{CacBg_Ayp@kn@q~@o}@ovAezBsnCcp@sHi\\mSwdA}jBqwAi|@uq@gmAeuAigAi{Bgy@ofCoyAa`Aqd@}p@qj@gr@{a@sbA{Su|C{sB}nAqf@kzAvYio@nPm[vWub@jp@kXbKwwAsl@sw@ccBc\g_Agt@yiFmDcmAuU{q@_hBimAik@kh@qK}k@ar@wxCqW{w@qi@my@g[yhB}\cmBsu@wgBqqAexB{Jur@dBuqBoFyi@nMa}@kSovAib@{cAyjCeqH_z@a`Cwl@yy@sWu|@mpBsaB{vAepDmr@wcCy^{q@odAku@oaDiuBueDqqBu`ByyBimAqlAomBozA{cAgy@{rBkbAorCkx@_m@yr@il@wp@s{@seEsx@ccCw^}pCwNigCuw@i`CccAaxC{d@u}BkbA{gG}n@}tBwSy_BgUeeDgSexAcb@maAof@_nBaH}mCuB}kB{TayAUkiE_HabBjJi~B}Ky|@iy@w~BuxC_hD}_AooDwn@m}Ds`@}tBs^su@kj@q_AcQe{@cGe~A_n@khB}e@mcDtPogC|DgiCe^{nAeP}y@u[af@y}@_gCcZmpFqFwsAwUuu@qSatBkH}oAiu@w}FO_lGBk{AbOs^`b@gbAjG_{D|DewBo_@eOg\m_@}XzML~QpJfEcBxOwAl@'}, u'warnings': [], u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 42.3607971, u'lng': -71.0504669}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 40.7127243, u'lng': -74.01186779999999}}, u'waypoint_order': [], u'summary': u'CT-15 N and I-90 E', u'copyrights': u'Map data \xa92016 Google', u'legs': [{u'distance': {u'text': u'216 mi', u'value': 347410}, u'end_address': u'Boston, MA, USA', u'via_waypoint': [], **u'duration_in_traffic': {u'text': u'4 hours 3 mins', u'value': 14601}**, u'start_address': u'New York, NY, USA', u'start_location': {u'lat': 40.7127243, u'lng': -74.0065046}, u'steps': [{u'html_instructions': u'Head northwest on Steve Flanders Square toward **Broadway**Restricted usage road', u'distance': {u'text': u'236 ft', u'value': 72}, u'travel_mode': u'DRIVING', u'start_location': {u'lat': 40.7127243, u'lng': -74.0065046}, u'polyline': {u'points': u'ounwFrkubMINABCDMZSd@Ur@'}, u'duration': {u'text': u'1 min', u'value': 9}, u'end_location': {u'lat': 40.7130849, u'lng': -74.00721879999999}}

...

u'lng': -71.05981249999999}}]}]

Comment: To python this is a list with one element. I don't know how to iterate it. Could you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
l = [ { 'key': 'value' }, { 'key' : 'othervalue' } ]
print(json.dumps(l))
```

You should see something like:

> [{"key": "value"}, {"key": "othervalue"}]

You might then try this:

```
string_data = """[{"key": "value"}, {"key": "othervalue"}]"""
structure = json.loads(string_data)
print(structure[0])
print(structure[1])
```

The structure you show appears to be a JSON encoded data structure consisting of `list`s and `dict`ionaries. You can use `json.loads()` to load a string (convert from JSON to native data structures). Then dump it via print and figure out the sequence of indexes (like [0]) and keys (like ['duration_in_traffic']) you'll need to get the data you want.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great start. I'm trying to figure out what to feed to the json.loads command. The API returned the list I posted above, but when I do structure = json.loads(api_returned_listname), I'm getting a type error: "TypeError: expected string or buffer". Do I need to transform that list to a string first?

Comment: It's possible the JSON has already been extracted. What happens when you do a `print(len(api_returned_listname))` ?

Comment: print(len(directions_result)) yields 
1

Comment: So it's already a list - you don't need to `json.loads` it. Just set `d = directions_result[0]` and you apparently have a dict. Try `print(sorted(d.keys()))` and see if it gives you anything useful.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I'm not sure however if this is useful: print(sorted(d.keys())) yields: 
[u'bounds', u'copyrights', u'legs', u'overview_polyline', u'summary', u'warnings', u'waypoint_order']

Comment: Looking up at your OP, you want `legs` as your next key. That will give you a list of dictionaries, which include `duration_in_traffic`. So: `directions_result[0]['legs'][0]['duration_in_traffic']`. Please note that I don't have any idea whether there can ever by a `legs[1]`, and if so under what circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

This code will extract the snippet you are looking for:

[image: pyDemo]

This is the RexEx pattern used the above demo:
`u'duration_in_traffic.*?}`

[image: rxDemo]

Try it out @ this **[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR6oF3/1)**